# phone field is not displaying in stripe checkout page javascript

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, angular14

```
strikeCheckout.open({
  name: this.product.product_name,
  description: 'Payment widgets',
  amount: +amount * 100,
  phone:'',
  address: {
    mode: 'shipping',
  },
  currency:'inr'
});
```

I am using this code base all fields are visible except phone, i want to display phone field in my stripe checkout configuration page aswell

Comment: What does your session creation look like? should use `phone_number_collection` as [stated in the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/phone-numbers), does it?

Comment: What is "strikeCheckout" (misspelled?) and where is the `open` method defined?

Answer (score 0):

trikeCheckout.open({
name: this.product.product_name,
description: 'Payment widgets',
amount: +amount * 100,
phone:'',
address: {
mode: 'shipping',
},
currency:'inr'
});**
**
**strong text**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tried Already but not worked

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using the Legacy `checkout.js` integration pattern, which has been deprecated for several years. You should look at [migrating to the modern Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration) flow, which supports [phone number collection](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/phone-numbers).

Comment: Can we Implement Stripe without Backend, Just to apply widget in our html page, can someone provide any stackbizz or codepan or some reference which i can use, my requirement that widget should have Shipping Address and Phone number field Enable, the buy now is not allowing the real payment aswell.

Comment: You can do this using Payment Links (or a Buy button), and enable phone number collection when you configure the payment link:
https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/share
https://stripe.com/docs/payment-links/customer-info#collect-addresses-and-phone-numbers